# Error parsing parameters in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, parsing, parameters

I'm having a problem parsing my parameters in ASP.Net

Here's what i'm doing

```
    Sub ItemCommand(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "EditDetails" Then

    EditDetails()   <---- This is where it's dying
    Else If e.CommandName = "SubmitDetails" Then 
        SubmitDetails()
    End If

    End Sub

    Sub EditDetails(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

    Dim strPassedItems = e.CommandArgument

    Dim strNumberSlept As String = e.CommandArgument.Split("-"C)(0)
    Dim strPassedBookingRef As String = e.CommandArgument.Split("-"C)(1)

    CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditAdults"), dropdownlist).Visible = True
    CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditChildren"), dropdownlist).Visible = True

    End Sub
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you are calling EditDetails()   without any parameters whereas your method expects two parameters. Does this even compile? if so, you should be calling method like EditDetails(sender,e)

Comment: That worked - I'm a real newbie to this sorry - I was adding the whole `ByVal Sender` etc didn't realise you only needed to put `sender,e` many thanks

Answer (score 0):

EditDetails - doesn't it require two arguments passing in? Sender and e?

**EDIT:**

Can't remember in vb - but try EditDetails(sender, e)

Comment: If I add that in like this `EditDetails(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)` Then I get an error `expression expected`??